# Dropwizard client type mismatch

Tags: java, eclipse, jersey, client, dropwizard

First a bit of background, I am trying to design a RESTfull app in Eclipse and I've been teaching myself DropWizard in pieces using the pdf book available here: https://github.com/adhulappanavar/Dropwizard/blob/master/RESTful%20Web%20Services%20with%20Dropwizard%20%5BeBook%5D.pdf

The books about two years old so there have been a few errors I've encountered because of that but the following error from my application entry class (rappApplication) is really stumping me.

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient cannot be cast to com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client
at edu.udel.rapp.rapp.rappApplication.run(rappApplication.java:50)
at edu.udel.rapp.rapp.rappApplication.run(rappApplication.java:1)
at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:43)
at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:85)
at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:75)
at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:79)
at edu.udel.rapp.rapp.rappApplication.main(rappApplication.java:31)
```

In this class:

```
import io.dropwizard.Application;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment;

import org.skife.jdbi.v2.DBI;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import io.dropwizard.Application;
import io.dropwizard.Configuration;
import io.dropwizard.client.JerseyClientBuilder;

import io.dropwizard.jdbi.DBIFactory;
import edu.udel.rapp.resources.ClientResource;
import edu.udel.rapp.resources.StudentResource;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;



public class rappApplication extends Application<rappConfiguration> {
private static final Logger LOGGER =
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(rappApplication.class);

public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    new rappApplication().run(args);
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "rapp";
}

@Override
public void initialize(final Bootstrap<rappConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    // TODO: application initialization
}




@Override
public void run(rappConfiguration c, Environment e) throws Exception {

    final Client client = new JerseyClientBuilder(e).build("REST Client");
    e.jersey().register(new ClientResource(client));


    LOGGER.info("Method App#run() called");
    for (int i=0; i < c.getMessageRepetitions(); i++) {
    System.out.println(c.getMessage());
}
System.out.println(c.getAdditionalMessage());
// Create a DBI factory and build a JDBI instance
final DBIFactory factory = new DBIFactory();
final DBI jdbi = factory.build(e, c.getDataSourceFactory(), "mysql");
// Add the resource to the environment
e.jersey().register(new StudentResource(jdbi, e.getValidator()));
}






 }
```

Now in the book, the initialization of the client in my run method **did not** require casting to Client, but Eclipse gives me a compilation error ("Type mismatch: cannot convert from javax.ws.rs.client.Client to com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client") if I don't cast to Client there...which then causes the error at run time.

Also, I'm confused as to why Eclipse is having a problem with "org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient" when what I imported for my class was io.dropwizard.client.JerseyClientBuilder;

It's almost like Eclipse is confused as to what the Client actually is.

EDITS: I'm using Maven with the following dependencies in my pom.xml,

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-testing</artifactId>
    <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-client</artifactId>
    <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-assets</artifactId>
    <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-forms</artifactId>
    <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.190</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
    <version>v3-rev32-1.22.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-jdbi</artifactId>
    <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>




</dependencies>
```

**Performing mvn clean dependency:tree gave the following output**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building rapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ rapp ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ rapp ---
[INFO] edu.udel.rapp:rapp:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.7:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-testing:jar:1.0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-util:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.7.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jackson:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.7.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-guava:jar:2.7.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.7.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.7.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner:jar:2.7.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.7.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-validation:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.2.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-configuration:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.7.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-logback:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.3.9.v20160517:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-metrics:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jersey:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-metainf-services:jar:2.23.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:jar:2.23.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jersey2:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.7.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.7.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.7.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.23.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.3.9.v20160517:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.3.9.v20160517:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.3.9.v20160517:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.3.9.v20160517:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.3.9.v20160517:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jetty:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jetty9:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.3.9.v20160517:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.3.9.v20160517:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.3.9.v20160517:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.3.9.v20160517:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-lifecycle:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlets:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-healthchecks:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-request-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-access:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sourceforge.argparse4j:argparse4j:jar:0.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain.setuid:jetty-setuid-java:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.0.54-beta:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.3.16:test
[INFO] |  +- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.4.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers:jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory:jar:2.23.2:test
[INFO] |     +- org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework:jersey-test-framework-core:jar:2.23.2:test
[INFO] |     |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.23.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-client:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.23.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-httpclient:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.connectors:jersey-apache-connector:jar:2.23.2:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-assets:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-servlets:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-annotation:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-forms:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:jar:2.23.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.190:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:jar:17.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:jar:1.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-java6:jar:1.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:jar:2.5-20081211:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:jar:v3-rev32-1.22.0:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.6:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jdbi:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-db:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jdbi:jdbi:jar:2.73:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jdbi:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.3.0-b05:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.3.0-b05:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.3.0-b05:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.3.0-b05:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.3.0-b05:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Comment: It's a clear dependency mismatch issue. Please explain which build tool are you using, and provide the dependencies used.

Comment: @code just updated my op

Comment: Looks like dependency conflict with jersey-core. Make sure you exclude this dependency from all other dependencies to ensure some other version is not being used at runtime

Comment: @code Thanks for all the help! I'm not familiar with dependency conflicts or exclusions so bear with me; I did tinker with the pom.xml based on the little bit of research I was able to do but no dice, if I didn't include the (Client) in my application file it returned the compilation, and if I did it gave me the aforementioned run time error. Maybe I'm doing the wrong thing with the exclusion? Also, for future reference, is there a way to tell if its a dependency mismatch issue?

Comment: Your *edit 2* is not useful and it's wrong. Read about maven dependencies, how they are injected into your project. <exclusion> tells to maven not to include that artifact(that is part of dependency from which you are excluding) in your project. Some other version of Jersey-core could be coming from any other dependencies(as a transitive dependency). Also, try out adding jersey-server as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906534/java-lang-classcastexception-org-glassfish-jersey-servlet-servletcontainer-cann

Comment: @code okay, I will do what I can research wise when I have the time. I did try adding jersey server and it did not change anything. Also, I don't know if this clears anything up but completely removing the jersey-core dependency at the end of my POM does not change any behavior at build/run time.

Comment: *completely removing the jersey-core dependency at the end of my POM does not change any behavior at build/run time.* That's most probably because, some other dependency is bringing the *jersey-core* to your project. Run this command tell me how many jersey-core are present in the output: `mvn clean dependency:tree`

Comment: @code just performed the command.

Comment: Looks like it's not a jersey-core related issue. As you mentioned, after removing the jersey-core dep from pom and from your dep tree it shows that you don't have any transitive dep on jersey-core, you don't need jersey-core dep at all.

Comment: @code I'm trying to identify if there are any other dependencies which could be causing the problem, but I'm really not familiar with Maven. Is there anything I can do to attract more answers to this post because I am pretty much flying blind here, and I am way too busy to spend allot of time diving into a new technical area.

Comment: @code  I have reached out to the publisher of the book and the author has confirmed that it is a dependency issue but they (he?) did not specify what exactly was causing the dependency issue.

Answer (score 2):

As the code shows [here](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-client/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/client/JerseyClientBuilder.java),

```
new JerseyClientBuilder(e).build("REST Client");
```

returns an instance of type `javax.ws.rs.client.Client`. But you have imported `com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client` in your code.

Replace

> import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;

with

> import javax.ws.rs.client.Client

Comment: Unfortunately I had already tried to do that and it didn't work; it was because of a number of different errors that pop up so I will see if there's a way to work around those and make this work. That said, the book author did confirm that there is something wrong with the dependencies, and I'm hoping to hear back from them soon with specific details.